# Angular Rails app with authentication and token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, authentication, devise

I am building a very simple app using angular js as frontend and rails as backend. When building only using rails, it was simple to use devise gem and work with rails views (erb). But now the scene is entirely different for me. I wish to keep both the codebases in separate repositories and run both servers separately (grunt and rails server). Here are my queries (if somebody could answer)

1. How to manage authentication ? I tried using angular devise but it was not overriding hostname and port for all requests, I had to do it for all type of requests. Also, devise renders its own views after authentication is complete or if it fails. For sessions#new controller, it never lets me override and does its own work.
2. Any other recommended approach/ a gist or a tutorial which can guide me to manage sessions between rails/angular js ? I am new to this approach (rails-angular thing)

Thanks alot in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Devise is the best option for authentication.

For Rails backend follow this [admin static content](https://github.com/vishal-netsol/admin_static_content)

For angular frontend follow this [Angular Admin UI](https://github.com/vishal-netsol/admin-angular-ui)

Comment: The README files of both repositories don't reveal much about it. Can you elaborate a bit about these ?